# why do i have to add a capacitor to observe AM output

Tags: rf, modulation, amplitude-modulation, demodulation

so our TA asked us to simulate this modulator in lTspice but told us to add a capacitor that has a value of 0.1 uF at the output and record the result and confirm the envelope shape from message signal and bandwidth etc..

then he told us to use this demodulator and connect to extract the message signal from the AM  signal
can anyone explain what the sets of resistors and capacitors do in these circuits i know that the carrier null is adjustable so that it produces a DSB signal im really confused

[image: this is the modulator without the capacitor at the end]
[image: this is the demodulator]

Comment: The MC1496 is really really well-documented. Not just on its datasheet but also on whitepapers, too. But that said, it's not even clear to me what you mean when you ask, "what the sets of resistors and capacitors do in these circuits?" You've provided three sections of circuits. Do you mean in all of them? That you want everything explained in all three sections?

Comment: @jonk hey im terribly sorry but our TA told us to take it directly from the datasheet  and just add a cpacitor at the output, i will tell you what i know about the modulator circuit the gain is determined by Re , modulation index is adjustable using the carrier null in R1 and the 6.8 k resistor connected to pin 5 determines the bias current . is there any other vital component im missing ? i just want to understand how the circuit works because the TA didnt mention the working principle of the circuit

Comment: It’s a multiplier Ic so you get a 50 ohm load approx on carrier , an offset adj. on the signal, which is a diff input but using single ended input which modulates current gain along with Re and Rbias  while the differential open collector outputs have pullup R’s so the said 0.1uF shunt across 3k9 might attenuate above 1kHz which might be Ok for the unused output, but not the used one for single ended output.

Comment: @lolls222 Again, I see three sections. When you write, "i just want to understand how the circuit works" are you just talking about ONLY the Gilbert stuff inside the MC1496 and how that works with the external circuit around it?

Comment: @jonk only the external circuit

Comment: Gain =22 x 22 then positive peak detector with RC filter removes carrier and shows modulation

Comment: @lolls222 So... what's the question, again? Could you maybe just list a few parts to start that don't make enough sense to you, yet? Start small? Maybe I'll get a clue, yet.

Comment: I think she/he meant series 0.1uF cap to remove DC offset from modulator

Comment: @jonk RL C1 and C2 in the external circuit

Comment: @lolls222 Oh. Yeah. That's drawn a little funny, I suppose. You should try and redraw that mess. \$C_2\$ is just stabilizing the resistor divider's midpoint voltage rail. It's drawn so as to look a little like something else, but I think that's because they were trying to densely pack parts around while still maintaining some kind of "in on left" and "out on right" sense. Does that much make sense? Do you know at all ***why*** such a midpoint voltage might be desirable with the MC1496?

Comment: @lolls222 Okay. Enough time. This really sounds like you may need a long dialog about what's in the MC1496 -- and every single bit of it is WORTH studying, in detail. It's a fantastic toolkit that can be used for way many more functions than they show. Kind of a Swiss Army knife. Just a little more subtle about its features than a 555 is about its, I suppose. That would require a lot to be written here, I think. The nice thing about the MC1496 is that there are only three relatively simple sections to understand. Then things are really easy, after.

Comment: @jonk honestly no but i will search why and i will learn gradually how it all adds up together and understand how the external circuit works and the vitality of each component

Comment: Is a function generator supplying the modulating signal to \$V_S\$  directly? If so, the **carrier null** variable resistor won't be able to give you proper AM. The function generator's **DC offset** control *will* be able to adjust for proper AM.

Comment: @lolls222 Look on page 8 of the datasheet, Figure 23. There are two pairs of BJTs whose bases are hooked up to pins 8 and 10. Below them are two more BJTs tied to pins 1 and 4. And finally below that there are two more BJTs tied to pin 5. Pin 5 sets two identical sink currents. The BJTs above them, tied to pin 1 and 4, must have their bases *above* those tied to pin 5. Finally, the pairs of BJTs (8 and 10 pins) have their bases still higher. Some kind of mid level DC voltage is needed to bias those BJTs tied to pins 8 and 10.

Comment: @jonk yep found it

Comment: @jonk thank you very much you really helped me alot in understanding this modulator circuit